# Excluding unmanaged dependencies from universal:packageBin in sbt-native-packager?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have an external lib directory with jars. I need these included in my classpath in order to compile and test my project but I do not want to include them in the distributed zip file that is generated via `universal:packageBin` (in the [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)) (or `dist` if you're using the `playframework`.

I attempted to do this by using the `provided` scope as follows:

```
unmanagedBase in Provided := new java.io.File("/external/lib")
```

But this doesn't seem to work as advertised - the jars don't seem to get included in the `Compile` scope.

I am using sbt **0.13.1**.

Comment: Try `unmanageBase in packageBin := file("/external/lib")`

Comment: unfortunately, @laughedelic, that removes the deps from Compile scope - I still need them there :(

Comment: Doesn't `unmanageBase in Compile := file("/external/lib")` help with both `Compile` scope and `packageBin` task? If no, you can just set both separately.

Comment: sorry, you misunderstand - I want the umanaged jars in compile (and test) but I *don't* want them included in the binary distribution. I am basically trying to replicate what Provided scope does in maven.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works (thanks @jacek-laskowski for the improvements to my answer):

```
mappings in Universal :=  (mappings in Universal).value.filter { case(jar, _) => jar.getParentFile != unmanagedBase.value }
```

But, it still feels like a kludge, I would much prefer it if `sbt` (and the `sbt-native-packager`) would properly support the `Provided` scope as this scenario is exactly what it is meant for.

Comment: I would avoid using `!_._1` and replace the predicate in `filter` with `{ case (x,y) if ... => ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose the following solution:

```
mappings in Universal := (mappings in Universal).value filter { case (jar, path) => 
  jar.getParentFile != (unmanagedBase in Compile).value
}
```

It duplicates `mappings in Universal` that could be avoided with `~=`, but then no `.value` macro support offered.

I think the solution is however type-safe since it uses the value of `unmanagedBase in Compile` setting that's `java.io.File` (not `java.lang.String` which is prone to typos).